# Problem solving an induction problem

Tags: induction

> Show that for every  $n\ge1$ and for every real number $x\ne 1$
> $\dfrac {x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n$ is valid.

By induction,  put $n=1$ $x=2$ and you get for the base case:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$$
$$x+1=x+1$$

Then consider $n=m$

$\dfrac {x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^m$  and assume that holds.

We then calculate $m=n+1$:

$\dfrac {x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n+x^{n+1}$
I get:

$$\frac{x^{n+2}}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n+x^{n+1}$$

Multiply by $x-1$ and get:

$$x^{n+2}-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n+x^{n+1})$$

But how do we get further here?

Comment: The dots mean that you only go up to the $n$-th power. For $n = 1$ you ignore the $x^2$ and everything ""after"" for example.

Comment: The base case ($n=1$) is not what you wrote. The lhs should be $\frac{2^2-1}{2-1}=3$ and the rhs should be $1+2^1=3.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks. How is that wrong?

Comment: @Bruno B @1=1@ then. Thanks

Comment: No, $1=1$ is the case $n=0,$ which is off topic in this exercise.

Comment: Luthier, for $n=1$ you have $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=1+\cdots +x^n=1+x^1$. For $x=2$ this yields $3=3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks!

Comment: Hint for the proof: just see what happens when you calculate $(x - 1) \sum_{k = 0}^n x^k$, there is no need for induction.

Comment: @BrunoB I don't get that sum to be equal to the LHS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $n=1$ and $x=2$, the equation becomes $$\dfrac{2^2-1}{2-1}=\dfrac{3}{1}=3=1+2$$ so the statement holds true.

---

#### Full proof by induction:

We shall induct on $n$. In this proof, $x$ can be any real number except for $1$.

**Base case:** When $n=1$, we have $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}=1+x$, which is clearly true.

**Induction hypothesis:** Suppose that when $n=k$, we have $\dfrac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^k$.

**Inductive step:** Consider the case where $n=k+1$.We claim that $\dfrac{x^{k+2}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{k+1}$.

By the induction hypothesis,
$$\begin{align}
1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{k+1}
&=\dfrac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}+x^{k+1} \\
&=\dfrac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}+\dfrac{x^{k+2}-x^{k+1}}{x-1} \\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{x^{k+2}-1}{x-1}}
\end{align}$$
This completes our induction.

Hence, for every  $n\ge1$ and for every real number $x\ne 1$, $$\dfrac {x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n$$

---

#### Alternative and more elegant proof:

Let $a=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n}$.

Then, $xa=x+x^2+\dots+x^{n}+x^{n+1}$.

Subtracting, we have $(x-1)a=x^{n+1}-1$.

Finally, dividing both sides by $x-1$, we get that $a=\boxed{\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}}$. Isn't that elegant?

Comment: Induction is quite overkill, but clean proof still.

Comment: Well, OP asked for induction proof, but I have edited my post to include an alternative proof.

Comment: Just checking, what is the intention of the first part with $n = 1, x = 2$?

Comment: At first, OP incorrectly said that when $n=1$ and $x=2$, the formula does not hold and asked why, so I included the explanation that the formula still holds.